# How to deal with nested Realm transactions in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, realm

I've been trying to make sense the following article explaining how to use Realm in Xamarin:
https://blog.xamarin.com/cross-platform-development-with-xamarin-forms-and-realm/.
Realm seems to integrate nicely with the xaml UI for simple objects, but how does this translate to more complex objects that have children?

When showing the add/edit page for an object, I need to show a list with all the object's children. I want to be able to show the add/edit page for those children when tapped in the list. The problem is that there is already a transaction open in the first add/edit page and I can't open a second one.

The only option I see so far is to not use transactions and to bind fields to separate member variables then copy those values in a Realm object and save it. But then I don't see the real advantage in using Realm.

Thank you!

Comment: In your `ViewModel` you can just pass in the current transaction, same as is shown in the example's `JournalEntryDetailsViewModel` constructor, you would do the same for when you show your children's page, pass in the current transaction. It really depends on how the view/edit logic flows within your app. and you can always fallback to using `.Manage` to persist the changes to an existing `RealmObject` (i.e. your `ViewModel` maintains a pseudo transaction and when ready to update the object(s) you then create a transaction and use `.Manage` to persist the changes...

Comment: Thanks @SushiHangover. I'll try something like that. I guess I need to get my head around xamarin first. I was wondering though if there was some more complex xamarin+realm examples out there, as I couldn't find anything substantial.

Comment: I do not know of any more complex examples that are public. I have quite a few that need updated to `v0.80.0` that I used as my working examples for the Realm-based project that I am working on (pushing around million record Realm instance now with the `v0.8` improvements). If I get some time, I'll update them and push them to github, but that does not help you today...

Comment: It really boils down to what your UI should look like. Do you want to have a cancel/done buttons or do you want to have the changes persisted as soon as they are made? And if you have cancel/done buttons, do you want the cancel button to revert the changes made on the current screen or all changes since the start of the edit?

Comment: @NikolaIrinchev, I would go for changes persisted as soon as they are made, Android-style. That means that I should actually save my object in realm as soon as the user taps the "add" button. Thanks for your inputs I will mark this thread closed and cogitate a bit on that !

Comment: @user1607256 in that case, you'll want to keep an eye on [this pull request](https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/pull/901). After it's merged, you'll be able to bind your UI to a RealmObject instance and when the setter is invoked (by a user interaction), a transaction will be automatically created and committed (if it's not already open), which should handle your use-case just fine.